# How to find the postFix of a string

Tags: c#

I have a list of filename in my folder and I convert the folder into a list. The file name is the same except for their postfix (number after the file name).
I want to get the latest postfix in that file list.

For example: In my list, I have 4 files. file_20160101 has the largest postfix. There for I want to get the name 'file_20160101' and add to my string.

```
[0] C:\\Desktop\\file_20130101.csv
[1] C:\\Desktop\\file_20140101.csv
[2] C:\\Desktop\\file_20150101.csv
[3] C:\\Desktop\\file_20160101.csv
```

Here is my code:

```
string fileDir = "C:\\Desktop\\"
List<string> list = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(fileDir));
string largestPrefix = //file_20160101.csv
```

Comment: If latest file is the last one saved in the folder, you can use file creation date to find the latest file.

Comment: string.Split would probably work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(fileDir));
var numericParts  = Directory.GetFiles(fileDir).Select(f => int.Parse(Regex.Match(f, @"\d+").Value)).ToArray();
var max = numericParts.Max(); //do whatever you want with the largest number
```

You can even call the `Max` directly in the case you don't need other numeric parts:

```
var max = Directory.GetFiles(fileDir).Select(f => int.Parse(Regex.Match(f, @"\d+").Value)).ToArray().Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are looking for the most recent file.You can try this (but yeah linq solution is better.:))

```
 string output = string.Empty;
 DateTime max = new DateTime();
 foreach(string str in list)
 {
            DateTime tempDate = new DateTime();                
            DateTime.TryParseExact(str.Substring(str.IndexOf("_") + 1, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-Us"), DateTimeStyles.None , out tempDate);
            if(tempDate > max)
            {
                max = tempDate;
                output = str;
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can give you result very quickly if you know that prefix will be always like "file_"

```
list.Max(f => int.Parse(f.Replace("file_", string.Empty)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
string result = "";
foreach (var item in list)
{
    int year = int.Parse(item.Substring(5 , 4));
    int month = int.Parse(item.Substring(9, 2));
    int day = int.Parse(item.Substring(11, 2));
    DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    if (currentDate > date)
    {
        date = currentDate;
        result = item;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```